# Reverse generic constraint with Borrow trait

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I've just learned about the `Borrow` trait.
From what I understand, the `Borrow` trait exposes a function `borrow` which works just like borrowing (i.e. `&`), but you can also use it in generic constraints (which you can't do with the normal borrowing syntax).

I have this function

```rust
pub fn get<Q>(&self, key: &Q) -> Option<&V>
    where K: Borrow<Q>,
          Q: Hash + Eq + ?Sized
{
    let bucket = self.bucket_key(key);
    self.buckets[bucket].iter().find(|&(ref ekey, _)| ekey.borrow() == key).map(|&(_, ref v)| v)
}
```

(I watched Jon Gjengset's video on YouTube)

And what is weird for me is that we constrain the `K` type, which is defined on the struct, to act like a `Borrow<Q>`.

So I was wondering what exactly this constraint says about `K` and `Q`.
Does it mean that we're constraining `K` to behave like a `Borrow<Q>`, or is `K` fixed here (since it was already defined on the struct) and we're constraining `Q` (and behind the scenes Rust converts it into something like `Q: Unborrow<K>` or something along these lines).

I hope that I make sense. I usually do C#, where something like that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get).

Don't overthink it. Rust trait system is basically a kind of logic, trait bounds are like logical constraints; here the type signature says:

- `Q` has to be `Hash`, `Eq` and `?Sized`
- `K` has to be able to be borrowed as `Q`

In practice, it is for convenience:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(String::from("a"), 1u32);
    map.insert(String::from("b"), 2);

    assert_eq!(map.get("a"), Some(&1));
}
```

The `map` variable here is of type `HashMap<String, u32>`. If it weren't for the `Borrow`, you'll have to write:

```
map.get(&String::from("a"))
```

but since `String` can be borrowed as `str` and `"a"` is of type `&'static str`, you can write:

```
map.get("a")
```

[The trait `Borrow` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#examples) has more elaborated explanation.

Comment: This is an HashMap that I'm writing by myself from a guide. I understand the Idea of constraints because they exist in C#, but what's confusing me is that `K` is a generic from the struct level and `Q` is a generic from the function level and it confuses me that you can constrain `K` at the function level, since it should be already well defined once you create the HashMap struct

Comment: @areller Functions may further constrain existing generic types, such as `K` in this example. This would mean that if you use the hashmap with a `K` that is not `Borrow<Q>`, then although you may use any other functions of the hashmap, you cannot call `map.get(...)`. Essentially this is an optional function for types that provide this functionality.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Great explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues not true. Since a value of `T` can always be borrowed as `T`, the `get` function is always available. With `Borrow`, it can accepts more argument types than just `&K`.

Comment: @edwardw Good point, but that is only true for `Borrow` (and other traits with blanket implementations such as that), but there are other traits that you can constrain at function level (or if `Q` was a generic at the strict level) that would make the function not available, which is the point of further constrains.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues well, since `Borrow` has a blanket implementation, the bound is actually more relaxed with it than without it. Saying `get` being optional is wrong in this particular case. But yes, it will be more restricting for other cases.